# Ajax post failing on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

I'm calling `ajax.php` with jQuery. It returns a JSON response all the time.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: 'some=info',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data != null) {
                console.log(data);
            } else {
                alert('IE fails here!');
            }
        }
    });
```

The Ajax always returns some data in JSON format. It works fine on all browsers except IE (tested on IE 7, 8 and 9). In IE it always prints the alert (which means that it never receives the response information). Any ideas?

**Update 1**: I just confirmed that the post is never successful in IE, that is why data is always null.

**Update 2**: the post arrives but returns null only when it is IE.

**Update 3 (solution)**: my fault, the ajax was protecting against calls from other servers. It uses an if() statement at the beginning which asks $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']'s host be the host of the same server. Now the question would be, **why doesn't IE recognize the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in the ajax call**?

This is the api code (php)

```
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $security = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        if(in_array($security['host'],array('localhost','tradukka.com','173.203.198.123'))) {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            $array = array('nice','data','for','api');
                echo json_encode($translation);
            }
        }
    }
```

IE fails at the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] check :s

Comment: but it is successful since it gets the alert. It's just null for some reason. Did you try doing success: and failure: ? You probably have error in the code somewhere else - IE doesn't like it and the rest is ignoring it.

Comment: Try to `console.log(data)` after the alert to see what data IE is getting, if any.

Comment: I just confirmed that the post is never successful in IE, that is why data is always null.

Comment: console.log(data) throws null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ajax was protecting against calls from other servers. It uses an if() statement at the beginning which asks $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']'s host be the host of the same server. the machines where i was testing on IE didn't get the host's name; instead it had the ip value, that is why it always threw false.

Answer (score 0):

IE is notorious for caching ajax requests.  Try adding the parameter 'cache: false' to your request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: 'some=info',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data != null) {
            console.log(data);
        } else {
            alert('IE fails here!');
        }
    }
});
```

*edit* Have you confirmed that there are no javascript errors being thrown?  Perhaps, being thrown and then caught with a try/catch, so might not be visible from the browser?

Comment: tried that already, it still responses null. The post action never arrives to ajax.php for some reason in IE only.

Comment: yeap, no javascript errors. the problem is when the browser tries to request the post response, somehow it catches null all the time :s

Answer (score 0):

Try this adding this before dataType: 'json'.

```
 beforeSend: function(x) {
  if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
   x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
  }
 },
```

So it should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: 'some=info',
    beforeSend: function(x) {
     if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
      x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
      }
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data != null) {
            console.log(data);
        } else {
            alert('IE fails here!');
        }
    }
});
```

Your server needs to send data as Content-Type "*/json" - If this code doesn't work, modify your response headers accordingly. Sending "application/json" would be fine, for example.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: didn't work :( i am using this on the server side (php) header('Content-type: application/json');echo json_encode($array);